# Actionscript 3 EventListener

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am fairly new to actionscript 3 and I would like to know how can I make EventListener to work only once. Right now it works after every click, but  I need to get it work only with first click.
After click it displays a ball on the stage where the click was made. I need to get to the point where only one ball appears and after that click should do nothing.

my code:

```
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick,false,0,true);
function onClick(evt:MouseEvent):void {
    var ball:MovieClip = new Ball();
    ball.x = stage.mouseX;
    ball.y = stage.mouseY;
    addChildAt(ball,0);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call [`removeEventListener()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/EventDispatcher.html#removeEventListener%28%29) as follows:

```
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick,false,0,true);
function onClick(evt:MouseEvent):void {
    stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);
    var ball:MovieClip = new Ball();
    ball.x = stage.mouseX;
    ball.y = stage.mouseY;
    addChildAt(ball,0);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

One possible solution is to remove the EventListener.

```
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick,false,0,true);
function onClick(evt:MouseEvent):void {
    stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);
    var ball:MovieClip = new Ball();
    ball.x = stage.mouseX;
    ball.y = stage.mouseY;
    addChildAt(ball,0);
}
```

Another solution is a simple bool variable, in case you need the eventlistener for something else.

```
var clickedOnce:Boolean = false;
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick,false,0,true);
function onClick(evt:MouseEvent):void {
    if(!clickedOnce){
       clickedOnce = true;
       var ball:MovieClip = new Ball();
       ball.x = stage.mouseX;
       ball.y = stage.mouseY;
       addChildAt(ball,0);
    }
}
```